# which one is faster when render HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. php return json, then javascript createElement to add data.

   ```
   type: 'POST',
   data: "do=view&start=0&stop=100",
   success:function(data){
       var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(data);
       var jExcel  = document.getElementById('jExcel');
       for(var i=0; i<parsedJson.id.length; i++) {
           var cell1 = document.createElement("input");
           var cell2 = document.createElement("input");
           cell1.setAttribute("type", "text");
           cell1.setAttribute("value", parsedJson.id[i]);
           cell2.setAttribute("type", "text");
           cell2.setAttribute("value", parsedJson.userName[i]);
           jExcel.appendChild(cell1);
           jExcel.appendChild(cell2);
           jExcel.innerHTML += "<br>";
       }
   }
   ```
2. php return `echo "<input type~~">`

Comment: You only provide the first method, no second one.

Comment: @fuyushimoya thanks.. my editor didn't work.. I changed with yours

Comment: If you mean echo something like `"<div>contents.....</div>"`, then the second, as javascript no need to handle other process, its left to server-side.

Comment: so you mean, when I render HTML code, the second one is faster?

Comment: The second one should be _faster_ at put content to view, as it takes less js operations, but I'm not sure if have other concern like internet flow ...etc, as the second should use more flow to send the whole content.

Comment: um.. thanks. I catch some ideas.. First render use php echo, second render with ajax in same page.. tahnk you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will find an answer for this that is 100% correct 100% of the time.

It comes down to the speed of downloading the html result vs the speed of java script DOM manipulation and this would vary depending on what variables are involved in the output, and how much data is to be produced etc.

In this case though, I would bet money that number two is the fastest case as 9 times out of 10, downloading the PHP response will be faster than DOM manipulation on the client side.

Go with method 2 unless you have to the time and know-how to accurately time these two methods.

I have to be honest, I have never seen anyone even consider method 1 and am interested in knowing why you have?

Comment: I think method 1 is just some transformation that it use `PHP` to retrieve data from `Database` and then he wants to put it to an existed table.

Comment: thank you. I want to render like excel. When someone open excel file(or csv) on my page I want to show the file with ajax..

Answer (score 1):

The first one gives your more control on the DOM elements since it's being created and handled first time in the browser client.

The second alternative will execute on the server-side, relieving the browser client of that task, thus making it faster for the client.

All in all, it really depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you're just displaying some information, I would stick to the second one.

Comment: If I render element with id, it can also control isnt it?